# Use ID to call a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 40 swatches each with an id. Upon clicking the swatch an image below should change and the text within the image will change as well. Currently I'm grabbing the id and using that to add to the URL of the image like so:

```
$('.swatches').children('img').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");

    $('#wallPic').attr('src', '//somepathtogettothisimage/theproductname_' + clickedId');
  })
```

Thant works great!

Also, inside my script I have all of the text saved as variables, like so:

```
var firstText = "Text for the first image",
    secondText = "Some other kind of text",
    thirdText = "Yet more text that's really different from the other two";
```

The id matches the variable when "Text" is added to it, so I assumed I could just do something like:

```
$('.swatches').children('img').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    var newText = clickedId + "Text"

    $('#wallPic').attr('src', '//somepathtogettothisimage/theproductname_' + clickedId);
    $('#imageText').html(newText);

  })
```

I assumed, in this case, "newText" would refer to the global variables ("firstText", "secondText", "thirdText", etc.). But, no dice.

Is there a way I can make the ID refer to the global variable to change the text? At one point I also tried turning the new text variable ("newText") into a string, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This is just an aside, but the world has gone jQuery crazy. jQuery is nice but you don't need it to do everything. In may cases, it's less code and more efficient to not use jQuery.  For example, this: `$(this).attr("id");` could just be this: `this.id;`

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus, that's a great point and I'll add that to my code.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner, more readable solution would be to use a javascript object, like so:

```
var imageTexts = {};
imageTexts['first'] = "Text for the first image";
imageTexts['second'] = "Some other kind of text";
imageTexts['third'] = "Yet more text that's really different from the other two";
```

Then, in your jQuery, modify the line as follows:

```
$('.swatches').children('img').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#wallPic').attr('src', '//somepathtogettothisimage/theproductname_' + clickedId);
    // Reference "imageTexts" with the clickedID (assuming 'first', 'second', etc)
    $('#imageText').html(imageTexts[clickedId]);

  })
```

Comment: Also $('.swatches').children('img') equals $('.swatches img') which i think is more clean.

Comment: I'm not doing a full code review / update - I'd approach this significantly differently than the OP - but I'm sure your comments will help the OP

Comment: Thanks @cale_b. If you have a moment could you give me a brief explanation on how you'd approach this?